Circular Summation of the forbidden Eisenstein series
This is Problem 1 of Chapter 9 from Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis:

There are several alternate ways of dealing with the sum $\sum\limits_{\omega\in\Lambda}\frac{1}{(z+\omega)^2}$, where $\omega=n+m\tau$ with $\operatorname{Im}\tau>0$. For example, one may sum circularly. Prove that if $z\notin\Lambda$, then
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(z+n+m\tau)^2}=S_1(z)$$
exists and $S_1(z)=\wp(z)+c_1$. (Notation: $\Lambda$ denotes the lattice.)

My attempt: By definition of the Weierstrass $\wp$ function
$$\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{(n,m)\neq(0,0)}\left[\frac{1}{(z+n+m\tau)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}\right],$$
it suffices to show that the limit
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}$$
exists. Then I follow the hint given in the book to evaluate the following integral:
\begin{align*}
    \int\limits_{1\leq x^2+y^2\leq R^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}{(x+y\tau)^2}&=\int_{1}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{r\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r}{(r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta\tau)^2}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta\tau)^2}\int_1^R\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r}\\
    &=\log R\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta\tau)^2}\\
&=\log R\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{(1+\tau\tan\theta)^2}\\
    &=\log R\left\{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+\tau x)^2}+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+\tau x)^2}+\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+\tau x)^2}\right\}\\
    &=2\log R\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+\tau x)^2}\\
&=0.
   \end{align*}
The last equality holds since $\tau$ lies in the upper half-plane. But then I get stuck, having no idea how to implement something like "integral comparison", for the series does not converge absolutely. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

I use a different way and obtain an explicit formula for this circular sum:
$$\fbox{$\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}=F(\tau)-\frac{2\pi i}{\tau+i}$}$$
where $F(\tau)$ denotes the forbidden Eisenstein series.

We first observe that
$$\sum_{m\neq0}\left[\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)\right]=0.$$
To see this, note that for any $m\neq0$, the inner sum converges absolutely since the summands are $O\left(\tfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$ as $n\to\infty$, hence it can be evaluated by
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{-N+m\tau}-\frac{1}{N+m\tau}\right)=0.$$
Thus, we can rewrite the forbidden Eisenstein series $F(\tau)$ as
\begin{align*}
F(\tau)&=\sum_{m}\left(\sum_{n}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}\right)=\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{m\neq0}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{m\neq0}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}\right)-\sum_{m\neq0}\left[\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{m\neq0}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2(n+1+m\tau)}\right).
\end{align*}
The last series converges absolutely by comparison with $\sum\limits_{m}\sum\limits_{n}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^3}$. Since
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}=\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}+\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\sum_{|n|\leq\sqrt{R^2-m^2}}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2},$$
we have
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}-\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^2}-\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\sum_{|n|\leq\sqrt{R^2-m^2}}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)\\
=&\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\sum_{|n|\leq\sqrt{R^2-m^2}}\left(\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}-\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)\\
=&\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\sum_{|n|\leq\sqrt{R^2-m^2}}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2(n+1+m\tau)}\\
=&\sum_{m\neq0}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2(n+1+m\tau)}\right),
\end{align*}
where in the last equality we have appealed to absolute convergence to justify rearranging the series. From the above we see that
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}=F(\tau)+\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right).$$
Now we shall focus on the last series and note that for $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we have
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)\\
=&\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\sum_{-\sqrt{R^2-m^2}\leq n\leq\sqrt{R^2-m^2}}\left(\frac{1}{n+m\tau}-\frac{1}{n+1+m\tau}\right)\\
=&\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\left(\frac{1}{m\tau-\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor}-\frac{1}{m\tau+\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor}+\frac{1}{m\tau+\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor}-\frac{1}{m\tau+\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor+1}\right)\\
=&2\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\left(\frac{2\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor}{m^2\tau^2-\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor^2}+\frac{1}{\left(m\tau+\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor\right)\left(m\tau+\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor+1\right)}\right)\\
=&2\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{\substack{-R\leq m\leq R\\m\neq0}}\frac{2\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor}{m^2\tau^2-\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor^2}\\
=&4\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1}{R}\sum_{1\leq m\leq R}\frac{R^{-1}\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor}{R^{-2}m^2\tau^2-R^{-2}\lfloor{Rf\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor^2}.
\end{align*}
Since $R^{-1}\lfloor{Rf\left(\tfrac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor\sim f\left(\tfrac{m}{R}\right)$ and $R^{-2}\lfloor{Rf\left(\tfrac{m}{R}\right)}\rfloor^2\sim f^2\left(\tfrac{m}{R}\right)$ as $R\to\infty$, the above limit is the same as the limit of the Riemann sum
$$4\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1}{R}\sum_{1\leq m\leq R}\frac{f\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}{\tau^2\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)^2-f^2\left(\frac{m}{R}\right)}=4\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{\tau^2x^2-f^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
To evaluate the last integral, we define $F(z)=\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)z^2-1}$ and consider its integral along the contour $\gamma=\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2\cup\gamma_3\cup\gamma_4\cup\gamma_R$ as shown below. Note that we can choose a single-valued analytic branch for $F(z)$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

It is obvious that the integrals along $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_4$ vanish as $\varepsilon\to0^{+}$. For $x_0\in(-1,1)$, if we denote $x_0^{\text{U}}$ the point close to $x_0$ in the upper half-plane and $x_0^{\text{L}}$ the point close to $x_0$ in the lower half-plane, then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Arg}F(z)\vert_{z=x_0^{\text{L}}}&=\operatorname{Arg}F(z)\vert_{z=x_0^{\text{U}}}+\Delta_C\operatorname{Arg}F(z)=0+\frac{1}{2}\left[\Delta_C\operatorname{Arg}(z+1)+\Delta_C\operatorname{Arg}(z-1)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(0-2\pi\right)=-\pi,
\end{align*}
and then
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^{+}}\int\limits_{\gamma_3}F(z)\mathrm{d}z=\int_{1}^{-1}e^{-\pi i}F(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-1}^{1}F(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$
Next we consider the integral along $\gamma_R$ (the circle with radius $R$). Since
$$\operatorname{Arg}\left(1-z^2\right)\big\vert_{z=Re^{i\theta}}\xrightarrow{R\to\infty}\operatorname{Arg}\left(-R^2e^{2i\theta}\right)=2\theta-\pi,$$
the integral of $F(z)$ along $\gamma_R$ as $R\to\infty$ becomes
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{Re^{i\frac{2\theta-\pi}{2}}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)R^2e^{2i\theta}-1}Rie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\to\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{i\left(2\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)e^{2i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{2\pi}{1+\tau^2}.$$
Therefore, by the residue theorem we have
\begin{equation}
2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{2\pi}{1+\tau^2}=2\pi i\left[\operatorname{Res}\left(F,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)+\operatorname{Res}\left(F,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)\right].\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}

These two residues at the simple poles of $F(z)$ add up to
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{z\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)}+\lim_{z\to-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}}\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)\left(z-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)}\\
=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\sqrt{1-z^2}\Bigg\vert_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}}\\
=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\left|\frac{\tau^2}{1+\tau^2}\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Arg}\frac{\tau^2}{1+\tau^2}}\left(e^{\frac{i}{2}\Delta_{P}\operatorname{Arg}\left(1-z^2\right)}-1\right)\\
=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\left|\frac{\tau^2}{1+\tau^2}\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Arg}\frac{\tau^2}{1+\tau^2}}\\
=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\left(\frac{\tau^2}{1+\tau^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
=&-\frac{\tau}{1+\tau^2}.
\end{align*}
Substituting this into ($\star$) gives
$$2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\left(1+\tau^2\right)x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\pi i\left(-\frac{\tau}{1+\tau^2}\right)-\frac{2\pi}{1+\tau^2}=\frac{-2\pi i}{\tau+i}.$$
Hence we conclude that
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{1\leq n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}=F(\tau)-\frac{2\pi i}{\tau+i}.$$
